# How to create a db creation script in ssms but for different db name

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I can create a script in ssms (2014) that would create my db on another server, all objects created, data as well if I like.

However the only way I can think to create it with a different database name is to edit the script using search and replace, possibly slightly risky.

Some of the stored procedures may ref the db directly by name, so I have to be careful or improve those.

Does anyone know an easy way to produce such a script but just with the whole thing referencing _b for example?

Comment: Can't you just restore the database with an original name and then rename it? Best way would be to use Visual Studio for it and check if the project builds correctly after you change the name.

Comment: Is renaming likely to throw up any internal inconsistencies?  Like (maybe) functions and procedures make reference to the old name still?  How will these be certain to be apparent?  I've never used visual studio for renaming and building a database, I'll take a look.

Comment: A reference to an unknown database will throw an error during build, that is how you know what to fix ;)

Comment: Never used Vis Studio with ssms before.  If it's fairly obvious I'll go for that thanks.  If there are hidden pitfalls / useful but non-obvious pointers, that'd be good to know.  Thanks again, appreciate it.  Once the db has better self consistency I guess repeat generate and rename should work fine.